# Как реализовать проверку, есть ли ТГ ID в базе данных, и если есть, то выводить пользователю что он уже зарегистрирован?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, aiogram-3.x

Не понимаю что написать в if, чтобы работал код так как нужно.

Код:

```
@dp.message(Command('start'))
async def cmd_start(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    user_username_without_dog = msg.from_user.username
    user_username = "@" + user_username_without_dog
    user_id = msg.from_user.id
    user_firstName = msg.from_user.first_name
    user_lastName = msg.from_user.last_name
    await msg.answer("Приветствую! Для продолжения пользования ботом, пройдите верификацию!", reply_markup=kbPhone())
    query = f"""SELECT * FROM testBotParsInTelegram WHERE tgID={user_id}"""
    try:
        with connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="",
            database="testBotParsTelegram",
        ) as connection:
            connection.cursor().execute(query)
            connection.commit()
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    if():
        await msg.reply("Вы не подтвердили свой номер телефона! Зарегистрируйтесь для продолжения пользования ботом.")
    else:
        await msg.reply("Вы уже зарегистрированы!")

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Какую бд юзаешь?

Comment: @Baggrisha в тегах же написал, mysql

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот это вот

```
async def cmd_start(msg: Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    user_username_without_dog = msg.from_user.username
    user_username = "@" + user_username_without_dog
    user_id = msg.from_user.id
    user_firstName = msg.from_user.first_name
    user_lastName = msg.from_user.last_name
    await msg.answer("Приветствую! Для продолжения пользования ботом, пройдите верификацию!")
    query = f"""SELECT * FROM testBotParsInTelegram WHERE tgID={user_id}"""
    registration = 0
    try:
        with connect(
                host="localhost",
                user="root",
                password="",
                database="testBotParsTelegram",
        ) as connection:
            try:
                connection.cursor().execute(query)
                connection.commit()
                registration = connection.cursor.fetchone()[0]
            except:
                registration = None

    except:
        pass
    finally:
        if registration == None:
            await msg.reply("Вы не подтвердили свой номер телефона! Зарегистрируйтесь для продолжения пользования ботом.")
        else:
            await msg.reply("Вы уже зарегистрированы!")
```

Comment: Не помогло решить проблему(((